# Quantile regression categorical data

Tags: regression, categorical-data, quantiles

I am planning to do an analysis on socio economic determinants of women health status. For health status, being my dependent variables, I have taken anemia as one of the variable. I want to do see whether the anemia status by different quantiles of wealth varies or not ?. If varies, whether the covariates explain the same relation in each quantiles. I have read literature most of the literature concentrated on dependent being the continuous variable. Some of the health related literature suggested to transform the categorical variable into continuous variable (this I hope will be a last option). What will be an appropriate method to follow for this kind of analysis.

Comment: Is your DV binary or ordinal? If so you can use probit regression to estimate quantiles of the underlying latent variable

Comment: its an ordinal variable (no anemia, mild, moderate and Severe)

Comment: Right So use probit.

Comment: How to validate the predicted variable and my categorical variable are same. I mean is there any test that can validate that my predicted variable measures the same that my categorical variable has measured.